# How can we find x-path expression for class ng-binding?

Tags: xpath, ng-bind

How can we find x-path expression for class ng-binding? Here is the example:

```
<div class="product_card-img-info">
                                            <h5 ng-bind="pack.name" class="ng-binding">Freedom Kuota Harian 1GB / Hari (28GB)</h5>
                                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below xpath. It will select all elements having class 'ng-binding'

```
//*[contains(@class, 'ng-binding')]
```